# Problem connecting Sharepoint 2010 to SSAS through a RSDS

Tags: reporting-services, excel-services, powerpivot, powerview

As the title says, I'm trying to create a [Report Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198312.aspx) on Sharepoint 2010 where I have an SQL2012 instance with the PowerPivot, SSRS and the sharepoint add-in configured.

I choose "Microsoft BI Semantic Model for Power View" and write the connection string, then select Windows Authentication. When I click "Test Connection" it displays: "The connection either timed out or was lost".

I tried opening SQL Managment Studio on the server and connecting to the remote server which has the SSAS instance and it does connect. I'm trying to find what is happening.

-Edit 1-

It seems the [problem][1] is from trying to connect from the sharepoint server to an external SSAS. Also, I have Sharepoint 2010, SQL2012 for Sharepoint and my SSAS are 2005, I don't know it that helps.

I added the SPN for MSOLAPSvc.3 (following this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27204/msolapsvc-3-service-missing-from-kerberos-delegation)) with:

```
setspn -A MSOLAPSvc.3/serverFQDN server
```

-Edit 2-

I was looking at the sharepoint logs, and it seems is the same problem as [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/07/12/sharepoint-adventures-the-connection-either-timed-out-or-was-lost-with-rs-datasource-to-ssas.aspx).

But I haven't found where to configure correctly the constrained delegation.

-Edit 3-

I created a spn for the domain account I'm trying to do the delegation to SSAS. Then I added the delegation to MSOLAPSvc.3 on the other server. And now sharepoint shows

> A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running.